# Efficient sort array by ParentId swift

Tags: swift

Given an array of dictionaries some of which have `ParentId` I need to sort them in ancestry order.

I have a working algorithm, but I am not sure it is actually efficient.

How can this be improved?

Sample data:

```
var dicts = [["ParentId": "eee82", "Id":"a0dq1"],
             ["ParentId": "pqrst", "Id":"eee82"],
             ["ParentId": "aaa1", "Id":"pqrst"]]
```

Sample output

```
["pqrst", "eee82", "a0dq1"]
```

I ran below in playground

```
import Foundation

// GIVEN this source...
var dicts = [["ParentId": "eee82", "Id":"a0dq1"],
             ["ParentId": "pqrst", "Id":"eee82"],
             ["ParentId": "aaa1", "Id":"pqrst"]]

func findParents(source: [[String:String]], this: [String:String]) -> [[String:String]] {
    var results = [[String:String]]()
    
    if let parentId = this["ParentId"],
       let parent = source.first(where: { $0["Id"] == parentId }) {
        results.append(parent)
        
        results.append(contentsOf: findParents(source: source, this: parent))
    }
    
    return results
}

var this = dicts.first!

var accounts = (findParents(source: dicts, this: this) + [this])

var sorted = [[String:String]]()

var hasParentMap = [String: Bool]()
for account in accounts {
    let parentId = account["ParentId"]
    let hasParent = accounts.first(where: { $0["Id"] == parentId }) != nil
    
    hasParentMap[account["Id"]!] = !(parentId == nil || !hasParent)
}

while sorted.count != accounts.count {
    for account in accounts {
        if sorted.first(where: { $0["Id"] == account["Id"] }) != nil {
            continue
        }
        
        if hasParentMap[account["Id"]!] == false {
            sorted.insert(account, at: 0)
            continue
        } else if let parentId = account["ParentId"] {
            let parentIndex = sorted.firstIndex(where: { $0["Id"] == parentId })
            if parentIndex == nil {
                continue
            }
            
            sorted.insert(account, at: parentIndex! + 1)
        }
    }
}


dump (accounts.map({ $0["Id"]! })) // ["eee82", "pqrst", "a0dq1"]

// ...we want to get this output
dump (sorted.map({ $0["Id"]! })) // ["pqrst", "eee82", "a0dq1"]
```

**Update** removed the numerical ids to avoid confusion

Here's the visual illustration of what I am trying to achieve

[image: Diagram]

Comment: `let sorted = dicts.sorted { $0["Id"] ?? "" < $1["Id"] ?? "" }`

Comment: What do you mean by "in ancestry order"? Do you mean dictionaries with the greatest parentID have the highest rank?

Comment: @LeoDabus that's sorted by id, got nothing to do with what i am asking

Comment: @RobertCrabtree No. I mean first the grandparents, then children, then grandchildren. Naturally grandparents are also born by someone but those guys are not living anymore hence they are not in our 'accounts' array.

Comment: @zaitsman what is the expected result? Post the resulting array

Comment: @LeoDabus i did it in the original question. Please see update, i removed the numericals  to avoid confusion

Comment: add the final array

Comment: i already did??? `["pqrst", "eee82", "a0dq1"]`

Comment: the sorted array of dictionaries that you applied map. What is your sort predicate? It is not clear how you want to sort its contents

Comment: @LeoDabus this is exactly my question :)) I can't express this as a simple predicate, i want to order them by `ParentId` such that the grandparents go before children before grandchildren (and so on)

Comment: Nobody knows who is the grandparent

Comment: @LeoDabus This one is the grandparent `"ParentId": "aaa1", "Id":"pqrst"` because there is no corresponding parent id in the source array

Comment: @LeoDabus I added a diagram that shows visually what I need

Answer (score 1):

To make things easier I created a Person type:

```
struct Person: Comparable, CustomStringConvertible {
    let id: String
    let parentID: String

    var description: String {
        return "[\(id), \(parentID)]"
    }

    static func < (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id < rhs.id
    }

    init?(dict: [String: String]) {
        guard let id = dict["Id"] else { return nil }
        guard let parentID = dict["ParentId"] else { return nil }
        self.id = id
        self.parentID = parentID
    }

    func toDictionary() -> [String: String] {
        return ["Id": id, "ParentId": parentID]
    }
}
```

Here is our data:

```
var dicts = [
    ["ParentId": "2", "Id":"3"],
    ["ParentId": "1", "Id":"2"],
    ["ParentId": "42", "Id":"1"],

    ["ParentId": "100", "Id":"88"],
    ["ParentId": "88", "Id":"77"],
    ["ParentId": "77", "Id":"66"],
    ["ParentId": "77", "Id":"55"],
]
```

Here are our people converted to structs:

```
var people = dicts.compactMap { Person(dict: $0) }
```

Here are a few methods to operate on our array of people:

```
extension Array where Element == Person {
    func tree(root: Person) -> [Person] {
        [root] + children(of: root)
            .flatMap { tree(root: $0) }
    }

    func topLevelParents() -> [Person] {
        return filter { parent(of: $0) == nil }
    }

    func children(of parent: Person) -> [Person] {
        return filter { $0.parentID == parent.id }.sorted()
    }

    func parent(of child: Person) -> Person? {
        return first { child.parentID == $0.id }
    }
}
```

Get all people who don't have parents:

```
let topLevelParents = people.topLevelParents().sorted()
print("topLevelParents: \(topLevelParents)")
```

Construct the tree of descendants for each parent and flatten into an array:

```
let results = topLevelParents.flatMap({ people.tree(root: $0) })
print("results: \(results)")
```

Convert back to a dictionary:

```
let dictionaryResults = results.map { $0.toDictionary() }
print("dictionaryResults: \(dictionaryResults)")
```